# *_join in dplyr - Returning only one combination of the match - R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to merge two data.frames in R, say a and b, with dplyr. Let's assume that the first is 20 rows x 4 columns; the second is 10 rows x 1 column - in common with the other. 
If i run

```
result <- full_join(a, b)
```

the result is 20 rows long - which was what I expected. However, I'm trying to find a way of getting a result which is only 10 rows long i.e it has the length of b but all the information in a for the matching entries.

I also tried with other *_join in the package but there must be something I'm missing here. Hope you can help me out with it. 
Cheers!

Comment: You must not have tried `right_join`? Or `left_join` if you do `left_join(b,a)`?

Comment: Even a `left_join(b, a)` may return more rows than in `b` if there is a 1:many match in the column being joined by.

Comment: Hi guys. I did. I should have specified that the column I'm using to join the data frames contains multiple matches of values of b in a. Maybe there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do but I could only think of merging the 2.

Comment: So you need to aggregate `a` first to avoid duplication of values. You can do it either through `unique` or `aggregate` functions.

Comment: The function `distinct` in `dplyr` might be the easiest way to do the aggregation.